# i am getting an uncaught syntax error at a line which is totally fine

Tags: javascript

on button click i am getting some rows returned from the database.

```
    $('#btnBasic').click(function () {
        $("#AdvanceCalculator").fadeIn("slow");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset= utf-8",
            url: "Calculator2.aspx/getAll",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                rowcounts = data.d.length;
                var data = data.d;
                var page_num = 1;
                initPageNumbers(rowcounts, data);
                getPage(page_num, data, rowcounts);

            },
            error: function (result) {

                alert(result.d);
            }

        });
    });
```

page-numbers is a div.
this function is for pagination and i think i am getting the syxtax error because of the $('#page-numbers').append(...) statement

```
    function initPageNumbers(rc, data) {

        $('#page-numbers').html('');
        total_rows = rc;
        //Loop through every available page and output a page link
        var count = 1;
        for (var x = 0; x < total_rows; x += rows_per_page) {
            $('#page-numbers').append('<li><a href="#' + count + '" class="item" onclick="getPage(' + count + ',' + data + ',' + total_rows + ');">' + count + '</a></li>');
            count++;
        }
```

//getpage()

```
    function getPage(page_num, data, rowcounts) {
        //Clear the existing data view
        $('#mixcontent').html('');

        //Get subset of data
        var count = 1;
        var val;
        for (var a = (page_num - 1) * rows_per_page; a < rowcounts; a++) {
            val = '<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3">' +
                        '<div class="thumbnail" > ' +
                            '<div class="caption">' +
                            '<h4 >NETWORK</h4>'+
                                '<h4 class="text-left" style="color:blue">' + data[a].Mix_Name +
                                '</h4>' +

                               ' <h4 class="text-left">Cost </h4>' +
                                '<h5 class="text-left">SMS </h5>' +
                                '<p style="color:black">Onnet - Offnet</p>' +

                                '<h5 class=text-left">CALL </h5>' +
                                '<p style="color:black">Onnet - Offnet</p>' +

                                '<h5 class=text-left">INTERNET </h5>' +
                                '<p style="color:black">MB - GB</p>' +

                                '<h4 class="text-left ">Subscription</h4>' +
                                 '<h5 >Validity</h5>' +

                            '</div>' +

                      '  </div>' +
                    '</div>';
            $('#mixcontent').append(val);

            if (count == rows_per_page) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

//rowcount is a global variable
//Mix_Name is the name of a column returned in query

the problem is whenever i click on the any of the page links, it shows uncaught syntax error: unexpected identifier in the console at the very 1st line of calculator2.aspx which is totally fine and here it is

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Calculator.Master" CodeBehind="Calculator2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Side_Practice.Calculator2" %>
```

I know this question is too narrow in scope and not gonna help any future visitors etc but i am just not getting the reason for this error. I'd deeply appreciate the help.

Comment: That will not be line 1 as far as the browser is concerned, because the server tags will not be output to the client. You need view source, or use the object inspector to see what is line 1 for the client.

Comment: Sidenote: What is the meaning of `data: "{}"` ?

Comment: data sent to the server which in this case is empty

Comment: See @Whelkaholism's comment. You've quoted everything except the actual output of calculator2.aspx/getAll, which is the crucial bit. Most likely, it's not outputting valid JSON, but we can't help you with what we can't see.

Comment: it is outputting the data i require. if you look at the code. the getpage method is getting called from 2 places. one from button click event which works fine and the other from $(#page-number).append method which i think is causing problems